# SQLSRV PHP Insert Problem with datetime conversion

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, sqlsrv

I'm having a problem doing an Insert query in a sql server DB when I try to put a date. The problem that I have is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string while inserting datetime

The query I am using is:

```
$sqlpedido = "
    INSERT INTO dbo.I_Pedido (id_cliente, Fecha, total, Comentario, portes, estado, FPago, id_destino, FormaEnvio) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
"; 
$params = array($ClienteID, $newformat, $gtotal, $cusnote, $shiptotal, '0', $paymethod,$id_destino, $shipmethod);
$stmt26 = $conn5->prepare($sqlpedido);  
$stmt26->execute($params);
```

The problem appears with the variable `$newformat`, I tried different forms to convert the date string provided from Woocommerce to datetime:

Option 1:

```
$dcreated = $order->get_date_created();
$d = new DateTime($dcreated);
$timestamp = $d->getTimestamp();
$formatted_date = $d->format('c');
```

Option 2:

```
$dcreated = $order->get_date_created();
$time = strtotime($dcreated);
$newformat = date('c',$time);
```

But no one of that options solved the problem... Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: give a sample `$order->get_date_created();`

Comment: Im trying all these methods because using this directly doesn't work

Comment: No i am saying can you give one example of `$order->get_date_created();`

Comment: @josesd What is the actual values of `$newformat` - a PHP DateTime object or a string, representing a datetime value?.And are you using Micorosft SQL Server (the `sqlsrv` tag is about SQL Server)?

Comment: $order->get_date_crated(); return 2020-09-14T05:21:42+00:00, i read about it and i think its formatted right, but its return the error

Comment: Yes i'm using SQL SERVER from PHP, and i'm trying to convert a string to datetime width the datetime class

Comment: @josesd I'm able to reproduce this error (without WordPress) with the following table `CREATE TABLE Data (DateTimeColumn datetime)`. What is the the data type of the `Fecha` column in `dbo.I_Pedido` table? Thanks.

Comment: The data type is datetime

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an unambiguous date\time format (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`), when you pass date\time values as text to `datetime` column in SQL Server.

The function `get_date_created()` returns [WooCommerce DateTime object](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-DateTime.html), so formatting the value using PHP [DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method is an option:

```
<?php

...
$newformat = $order->get_date_created()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');

$sqlpedido = "
   INSERT INTO dbo.I_Pedido (id_cliente, Fecha, total, Comentario, portes, estado, FPago, id_destino, FormaEnvio) 
   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
"; 
$params = array($ClienteID, $newformat, $gtotal, $cusnote, $shiptotal, '0', $paymethod, $id_destino, $shipmethod);
$stmt26 = $conn5->prepare($sqlpedido);  
$stmt26->execute($params);
...

?>
```